# display updating hash on webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an IRC bot that updates a hash key value upon a certain command. The values are either 'free' or 'taken'. When `lab status` is called it will show the output of the 4 key value pairs `{:MainSP4=>"Free", :MainSP5=>"Free", :MiniSP4=>"Free", :MiniSP5=>"Free"}`. I want to continuously display the output of `lab status` on a webpage and would like it to update as the commands are passed to the IRC bot. I have tried making a global variable and calling it but has not worked, although it may have just been user error.

***IRC bot***

```
require 'cinch'
require 'chronic'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'sequel'
require 'cinch/commands'

Lab =
{MainSP4: "Free",
MainSP5: "Free",
MiniSP4: "Free",
MiniSP5: "Free"}

LabC =
{MainSP4: " ",
MainSP5: " ",
MiniSP4: " ",
MiniSP5: " "}

############### DB Connection #####################
class Database
  include Cinch::Plugin

  match /select .* from gears where .* like .*/i

  def execute(m)
    db = SQLite3::Database.open("development.sqlite3")
    m.reply db.execute("#{m.message}")
end
end

############## Lab status and Commands ####################
class Racks
  include Cinch::Plugin

  match /lab status/i
  def execute(l)
    l.reply "#{Lab}"
  end
end
```

***View***

```
<% $Lab.each do |key, value| %>
    <li><%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
<% end %>
```

I have decided to go the websockets route. I have installed all the requirements to implement websockets with my rails app. Now I am stuck as I am not sure how to set up my websocketcontroller.rb, events.rb. I have read through the setup on the github wiki page but am still unclear. Any examples or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the contents of a web page without any user interaction, you have three possibilities :

1. Constant polling from your client to the server (high bandwith usage, easy to implement via jquery, will work out of the box)
2. Websockets (depends on your web server capabilities)
3. Server Sent Events (never tried this but it sounds promising as well)

Ilya Bodrov-Krukowski has a series of posts about this on sitepoint.

http://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails/ (constant polling)

http://www.sitepoint.com/realtime-mini-chat-rails-faye/ (websockets)

http://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails-server-sent-events/ (SSEs)

Hope you find the solution that suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how HTTP works. Once a web page is requested from a server, it renders it, sends it to the client and closes the connection. There is no further communication between client and server until another request is made. In order to do live updates on the client page there are several options available, all of which use JavaScript to do asynchronous communication between client and server:

The easiest option to implement is AJAX polling. The client is repeatedly connecting back to the server to check for the current value via JavaScript. Usually, a separate HTTP endpoint provides the data in JSON format to make it available to the client. When the value has changed, the JavaScript updates the DOM accordingly and the user sees the new value. This approach has the downside that clients will send lots of unnecessary requests, even if the values do not actually change. You also have a latency that is as long as the update interval in the worst case.

With web sockets, a separate connection is kept open between client and server and data can be sent back and forth between the two. With this approach, you will probably benefit from less overhead, quicker updates (no need to wait for the next update interval), and there will not be any communication unless the values actually change. However, this requires more effort to implement. Similar solutions can be implemented using long polling or persistent HTTP connections.